# How to traverse graph to graph in sparql query?

Tags: mysql, sparql, rdf, sparqlwrapper

[image: Graph diagrams]

How should I write SPARQL query to get the details from node2: URI for node2 is the same in both the graphs and URI for node 1 is different. Thank you in advance.

as such, I need the below details.

```
node2 def
hasID ghi
hasvertex jkl
hasLastname mno
```

Comment: This is the same as before, what's wrong with the query I suggested? `select distinct ?p ?o where {<http://diff/def> ?p ?o }` - what's wrong with this?

Comment: But I just have Node1 URI...Is it possible to traverse from Node1 and grab Node2 and other details. Thank you.

Comment: ok, but then you should say this in your question. "Given node1, how  to get node2 details" - and how to write basic SPARQL I told you yesterday, basically add a triple pattern per edge in your graph ...

Comment: `select distinct ?p1 ?o1 where {<http://ex/abc> ?p ?o. ?o ?p1 ?o1 }`

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience. I will try it out.

Comment: if not, please provide the RDF data and the expected result.

Comment: @UninformedUser : Hello Can you please suggest me some answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61187841/how-to-find-the-polygons-intersection-inside-apache-fuseki-server