# How to find the Polygons Intersection inside Apache Fuseki Server?

Tags: geospatial, polygon, jena, fuseki

I am using Apache Jena Fuseki Server for Storing Geo Coordinates of location. How to find out that if two polygons or two rectangles intersect each other inside Fuseki. Please share links related to it if possible. Thank you.

Hello...I am just updating question based on the below comments. Please suggest me regarding the problem I am facing. I have stored geocoordinates in WKT serialization format. When I execute below query

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX : <http://example.org/#> 
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX spatial: <http://jena.apache.org/spatial#>
SELECT ?object
WHERE { 
GRAPH <http://project/base/default> { 
    ?subject geo:asWKT ?object .
} }
```

I get these below results.

```
    object
1   
"POLYGON((8.463699817657472 48.99872928913063,8.463887572288515 48.998644821906865,8.46399486064911 48.998764483764916,8.46425771713257 48.99865538031766,8.464375734329225 48.998746886450874,8.463919758796694 48.99893693711346,8.463699817657472 48.99872928913063))"
2   
"POLYGON((8.463560342788698 48.99847940651206,8.463560342788698 48.99864834137738,8.46377491950989 48.99864834137738,8.46377491950989 48.99847940651206,8.463560342788698 48.99847940651206))"
3   
"POLYGON((8.463447690010073 48.99835974396915,8.463447690010073 48.99849348443939,8.463646173477175 48.99849348443939,8.463646173477175 48.99835974396915,8.463447690010073 48.99835974396915))"
4   
"POLYGON((8.463254570961 48.99821544463795,8.463254570961 48.99838438039854,8.463635444641115 48.99838438039854,8.463635444641115 48.99821544463795,8.463254570961 48.99821544463795))"
5   
"POLYGON((8.463689088821413 48.99826823712468,8.463689088821413 48.99845477012966,8.46402168273926 48.99845477012966,8.46402168273926 48.99826823712468,8.463689088821413 48.99826823712468))"
6   
"POLYGON((8.463892936706545 48.99843013373508,8.463892936706545 48.998588510344774,8.464316725730898 48.998588510344774,8.464316725730898 48.99843013373508,8.463892936706545 48.99843013373508))"
7   
"POLYGON((8.463093638420107 48.99805354732974,8.463093638420107 48.998243600637835,8.463737368583681 48.998243600637835,8.463737368583681 48.99805354732974,8.463093638420107 48.99805354732974))"
8   
"POLYGON((8.463619351387026 48.99797963751407,8.463619351387026 48.998180249615714,8.464118242263796 48.998180249615714,8.464118242263796 48.99797963751407,8.463619351387026 48.99797963751407))"
9   
"POLYGON((8.464407920837404 48.998303432084754,8.464407920837404 48.99857443244431,8.46477270126343 48.99857443244431,8.46477270126343 48.998303432084754,8.464407920837404 48.998303432084754))"
10  
"POLYGON((8.464225530624391 48.99806762537742,8.464225530624391 48.99839141937611,8.464820981025698 48.99839141937611,8.464820981025698 48.99806762537742,8.464225530624391 48.99806762537742))"
```

Then later I want to filter out these geo:WKT objects based on geo:intersection (Intersection or equals or contains methods). And I updated my query as below.

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX : <http://example.org/#> 
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX spatial: <http://jena.apache.org/spatial#>
SELECT ?object
WHERE { 
GRAPH <http://project/base/default> { 
    ?subject geo:asWKT ?object .
    ?object geo:equals "POLYGON((8.463699817657472 48.99872928913063,8.463887572288515 48.998644821906865,8.46399486064911 48.998764483764916,8.46425771713257 48.99865538031766,8.464375734329225 48.998746886450874,8.463919758796694 48.99893693711346,8.463699817657472 48.99872928913063))"
} }
```

Which should result me atleast the coordinates of first geo object which really equals the POLYGON coordinates but I get empty results as shown in below image. Please suggest me where I am getting it wrong.

[image: Screenshot for empty results returned in Fuseki]

Comment: See https://jena.apache.org/documentation/geosparql/ 

(this question has also been asked by email)

Comment: It is mentioned in the link "The spatial relations for the three spatial families do not apply to all combinations of the geometry shapes (Point, LineString, Polygon) and their collections (MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon). Therefore, some queries may not produce all the results that may initially be expected.".  Is that mean polygon intersection is not possible ? Please suggest me regarding this

Comment: why do you think this means *"not possible"*? Also, the Jena docs section that you cited state *"Refer to pages 8-10 of 11-052r4 GeoSPARQL standard for more details."* - the answer is on page 8 in the document referred to https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=47664

Comment: @UninformedUser  Hello sir, I have updated question , can you please help me regarding this. Thank you

Comment: `geo:equals` is a filter function and not a property function. This means it returns a boolean value, thus, you have to use it in a FILTER

(untested)

`FILTER(geo:equals(?object,
                              "POLYGON((8.463699817657472 48.99872928913063,8.463887572288515 48.998644821906865,8.46399486064911 48.998764483764916,8.46425771713257 48.99865538031766,8.464375734329225 48.998746886450874,8.463919758796694 48.99893693711346,8.463699817657472 48.99872928913063))"
                              )
           )`

Comment: SELECT ?object
WHERE { 
GRAPH <http://project/base/default> { 
    ?subject geo:asWKT ?object FILTER ( geo:equals(?object, "POLYGON((8.463699817657472 48.99872928913063,8.463887572288515 48.998644821906865,8.46399486064911 48.998764483764916,8.46425771713257 48.99865538031766,8.464375734329225 48.998746886450874,8.463919758796694 48.99893693711346,8.463699817657472 48.99872928913063))")) .
} }                                                                                                                             
This also returns me "no results." I modified query as below.

Comment: @UninformedUser: Hello sir, I have updated question , can you please help me regarding this. Thank you

Comment: I don't see any update in the question, still the same query and screenshot. Also not clear if your graph does contain any data at all. what is return with `SELECT ?object WHERE { GRAPH <project/base/default> { ?subject geo:asWKT ?object} limit 10`

Comment: It returns me strings ""POLYGON((8.463699817657472 48.99872928913063,8.463887572288515 48.998644821906865,8.46399486064911 48.998764483764916,8.46425771713257 48.99865538031766,8.464375734329225 48.998746886450874,8.463919758796694 48.99893693711346,8.463699817657472 48.99872928913063))" How should I convert it to "<http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#wktLiteral>" @UninformedUser

Comment: wait, I'm confused by your query. First, your should create a proper WKT literal. Next, which equals function do you use now? In GeoSPARQL it is called `geo:sfEquals`

Comment: you can try `?object geo:sfEquals "POLYGON((8.463699817657472 48.99872928913063,8.463887572288515 48.998644821906865,8.46399486064911 48.998764483764916,8.46425771713257 48.99865538031766,8.464375734329225 48.998746886450874,8.463919758796694 48.99893693711346,8.463699817657472 48.99872928913063))"^^<http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#wktLiteral>` - but this will only work if your objects are those literals

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211955/discussion-between-manoj-deshpande-and-uninformeduser).